# Displaying neatly formatted XML document with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, formatting

I'm building a classified adverts site and my listings are stored in an XML document. I load this document in to the listings page of my site using simplexml and then use foreach to display these.

At current everything works fine its just the formatting of the output I'd like to improve. Each listing is stacked on top of each other as such:

```
LISTING
LISTING
LISTING
LISTING
```

I would like them to be like this - 
LISTING LISTING LISTING LISTING and then once the edge of the column is reached, start on the next line.

Any help appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

**Relevant PHP code here -**

```
<?php
// Loading the XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("listings.xml");

foreach($xml->listing as $listing)
{
    echo "<u>Item ID:</u> ".$listing->id."<br />";
    echo '<img src="images/' . $listing->image . '"width="200" height="225">';
    echo "<br>Item: ".$listing->title." <br />";
    echo "Description: ".$listing->description." <br />";
    echo "Seller: ".$listing->seller." <br />";
    echo "Price: ".$listing->price." <br /><br />";
}
?>
```

**Relevant XML document here -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<advertlistings>
    <listing>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Another fucking cooker</title>
        <description>Best cooker of them all</description>
        <image>fractal pyramid.jpg</image>
        <price>3400</price>
        <seller>MJ420</seller>
    </listing>

    <listing>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>Shit cooker</title>
        <description>Shite cooker of the world</description>
        <image>1479991892439-1307203880.jpg</image>
        <price>2735</price>
        <seller>MJ420</seller>
    </listing>
</advertlistings>
```

Please ignore the descriptions etc, over the period of making this website cookers have become my worst enemy :p

Comment: if you want styling, start using CSS

Comment: That's something I haven't used a lot of and I can't think how I could get that to work with CSS when there's only the one for loop and the one div which that php section is in

Comment: The problem with your question is it can be answered very quickly, it will probably look like you want it, but you will not gain the understanding of why, without actually reading a full css tutorial, and without understanding how css relates to html and what it can achieve. This stuff is what you should learn, and it definitely doesn't fit in an answer here.

Comment: I've actually answered your question with a full blown example on how one could use both HTML markup and CSS styling + added notes on education etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that there is an answer but this answer is not what you are really looking for of sorts. This is a question that has everything to do with styling (CSS and HTML-markup) but much less to do with PHP.

The tag `formatting` as you use **is** in this case CSS + HTML so i'll provide you with an answer that has to do with how to format a list of listings.

```css
html { box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 62.5%; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
body {
 font-size: 1.4rem; font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; background: #fafafa; line-height: 1.5;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, aliceblue, #ffe);
 margin-top:40px;
}

/* simple table grid */
.row { display: table; table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 30px; }
.col { display: table-cell; height: auto; }

.ads {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 660px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.listing {
 width: 320px;
 background: #fff;
 z-index:0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 border-radius: 3px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.inner { padding: 15px; position: relative; }
.listing h3 { margin-top: 0; }
.listing img { width: 100%; height: auto; }

.listing .price {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
 color: #d00;
 display: inline-block;
 float:right;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute; top:-40px; right: 15px;
 background: #f44336; color: #fff;
}

.listing .seller { font-size: 1.1rem; color: #aaa; }

.listing button {
 border:0; background: #111; color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 clear:both;
 padding: 12px 0;
 margin: 30px 0 0;
 border-radius: 3px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.listing button:hover { background: #333; }

.listing { transition: transform .15s ease; }
.listing:hover {
 transform: scale(1.05);
 z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row ads">
 <div class="listing col">
  <img src="//placeimg.com/320/200/tech">
  <div class="inner">
   <h3>Another cooker</h3>
   <p>The best cooker of them all, with a lot of swearwords in it for no obvious reason.</p>
   <div class="price">$340</div>
   <div class="seller">Sold by MJ420</div>
   <button>Go to deal</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="listing col">
  <img src="//placeimg.com/320/200/any">
  <div class="inner">
   <h3>Some product here</h3>
   <p>The best cooker of them all, with a lot of swearwords in it for no obvious reason.</p>
   <div class="price">$195</div>
   <div class="seller">Sold by AR290</div>
   <button>Go to deal</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row ads">
 <div class="listing col">
  <img src="//placeimg.com/320/200/tech">
  <div class="inner">
   <h3>Another cooker</h3>
   <p>The best cooker of them all, with a lot of swearwords in it for no obvious reason.</p>
   <div class="price">$340</div>
   <div class="seller">Sold by MJ420</div>
   <button>Go to deal</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="listing col">
  <img src="//placeimg.com/320/200/any">
  <div class="inner">
   <h3>Some product here</h3>
   <p>The best cooker of them all, with a lot of swearwords in it for no obvious reason.</p>
   <div class="price">$195</div>
   <div class="seller">Sold by AR290</div>
   <button>Go to deal</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row ads">
 <div class="listing col">
  <img src="//placeimg.com/320/200/tech">
  <div class="inner">
   <h3>Another cooker</h3>
   <p>The best cooker of them all, with a lot of swearwords in it for no obvious reason.</p>
   <div class="price">$340</div>
   <div class="seller">Sold by MJ420</div>
   <button>Go to deal</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="listing col">
  <img src="//placeimg.com/320/200/any">
  <div class="inner">
   <h3>Some product here</h3>
   <p>The best cooker of them all, with a lot of swearwords in it for no obvious reason.</p>
   <div class="price">$195</div>
   <div class="seller">Sold by AR290</div>
   <button>Go to deal</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row ads">
 <div class="listing col">
  <img src="//placeimg.com/320/200/tech">
  <div class="inner">
   <h3>Another cooker</h3>
   <p>The best cooker of them all, with a lot of swearwords in it for no obvious reason.</p>
   <div class="price">$340</div>
   <div class="seller">Sold by MJ420</div>
   <button>Go to deal</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="listing col">
  <img src="//placeimg.com/320/200/any">
  <div class="inner">
   <h3>Some product here</h3>
   <p>The best cooker of them all, with a lot of swearwords in it for no obvious reason.</p>
   <div class="price">$195</div>
   <div class="seller">Sold by AR290</div>
   <button>Go to deal</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Run the snippet and show it 'fullscreen'.

---

#### JSFiddle

**https://jsfiddle.net/tommiehansen/0vr39L0k/6/**

---

#### Screenshot

[image: Example of how one could do]

---

#### Education

The example above is just one way one could do it but the point here was to show you that you're also asking a question for where there are aspects of *taste* involved and that the solution could be a plethora of different alternatives on exactly how to style things, what technique to use etc.

What you should be doing is take some sort of beginner course regarding HTML + CSS like this one on Codecademy:
**https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-html-css**

There are lots more courses out there but that one should get you started and be enought for you to grasp the basics and be able to do basic styling.

After that you could ask specific questions on HTML+CSS regarding some styling you wish to achieve and have problems with.

---

More samples

Also feel free to comment and ask for variations. Stacking div's is one of the most common things one can do in CSS and there are lots of examples avaible.

Here are some other examples of just laying things out:
Simple CSS-table grid: http://codepen.io/tommiehansen/pen/YWwGvZ
Using `display: inline-block` (color boxes): http://codepen.io/tommiehansen/pen/ZWNRoY

Also do use some of the examples as a base for your own testing. Learning by doing is a great way to learn things after all.